# stripping whitespace and limiting <br> in nl2br()

Tags: php

```
here is     a  lot    of      whitespace
<br>
<br>
<br>
3 br's is too many... i want to trim it to 2 <brs> in a row
```

How can I strip out this whitespace and limit the `<br>` to a max of 2 in PHP? So 1 `<br>` and 2 `<br>`'s in a row is acceptable. but anything over 2 gets trimmed to 2 `<br>`'s

Comment: when do you want to do this? and where are you getting the html from?

Comment: before entering it into the database from an input field

Answer (score 1):

Use `preg_replace`. To strip excess whitespace (limit to one space at a time):

```
$string = preg_replace('/\s\s+/', ' ', $string);
```

You can research on how to remove excess tags, but it would be another `preg_replace` operation using regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

use this str_word_count() and define preg_replace if then number of 
 is higher than 2
that would count all the 
 in the whole string. this lso depends on how many lines of string you have