# how to limit linebreaks on nl2br?

Tags: php, regex, newline

Kinda confused on how to do this.

I saw this question: [stripping whitespace and limiting <br> in nl2br()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16553625/stripping-whitespace-and-limiting-br-in-nl2br)

I kinda want to do the same but not sure how to do the code.

eg:

```
echo "<p><strong>Name:</strong></p>".nl2br($row['Achievements'])." ";
```

If I had:

- achievement 1
- achievement 2
- achievement 3

the nl2br would out put it like this:

achievement 1

achievement 1

achievement 1

how do i prevent the line break in between lines?

should be like this:

achievement 1
achievement 1
achievement 1

too many line breaks that I want removed.

```
$row['Education']= str_replace(array("\r\n", "\r", "\n"), 
                               "<br />", 
                               $row['Education']);
```

^ doesn't seem to be working

Comment: Questions or issues with answer?

Answer (score 2):

I think this should do it.

```
echo preg_replace('/[\r\n]+/', '<br />', 'test
test

test


test




test');
```

Output:

```
test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test
```

Regex 101 Demo: https://regex101.com/r/nO3aI9/1

The takes multiple new lines and replaces them with a single HTML line break.